# Close ado connection for access after finish update, and delete mdb file

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado, delphi-7

I'm trying to delete the mdb file after finished reading it.

The process is:

```
copyFile(originMdb, to targetMdb);
mdbConnection.active := true;
mdbQuery.open;
readMdbFileData;
mdbQuery.close;
connection.close;
deleteFile(tagetMdb);
```

But there is an ldb file that is generated that will not disappear.

update:
is there a way to tell the mdb, "i don't need any more connections now, close it, and remove the locks on the ldb file" 
instead the mdb engine is waiting for the process to end before it will release the connection that was made with adoConnection

update2: after creating a simple program that just opened and closed connection, the file is released, however since i hold an adoqury it refuses to releasea the file.

Comment: You shouldn't care about the existence or not of the LDB file. Also, Jet/ACE works better with persisent connections, so maybe you're applying non-application connection management practices where they don't offer any benefit. In short, I ask why you were worrying about this at all -- just let it be and see if it causes any problems.

Comment: the file needs to be deleted after it was processed, for a new file to come into the picture.

Comment: So, you mean the MDB file needs to be deleted, and you're just using the existence of the LDB file as proxy for the MDB being open? I don't know what to say. Apparently your development environment is not releasing the resources that will close the connection fully. Have you tried not just closing the connection but also destroying the instance of the database engine? I don't program in Delphi, so don't know how that would be done, but I"ve seen that be the solution in other circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wait and its depending on the size or your database. but you can also delete the ldb directly by creating another function.

for example:

```
Dim locationFLD As String
locationFLD = "yourLocation"
If Dir(locationFLD & "\*.ldb") <> "" Then
   deleteFile(tagetMdb) & ".ldb";
End If
```

Comment: The Access database engine disposes of the ldb when it is done with the mdb.  And the ldb is locked at the OS level until the engine releases it.  So I suspect this approach can only remove an ldb left over after an Access engine crash.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to wait for the connection to close and the jet engine to delete the ldb file.
the ldb file is a lock file created by the Jet Database engine

Comment: how long should i wait? is there a way to set the time to wait for release? can i force release immediately?